# Django count unique dates in queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset that return objects like this:

```
[
  {created_at: "2018-03-01"}, 
  {created_at: "2018-03-01"}, 
  {created_at: "2018-03-02"}
]
```

I want to select the count of unique days from my queryset. In the above example the expected answer would be `2`.

My current query look like this, where `created_at` is a `DateTimeField`:

```py
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

days = queryset.annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at')) \
    .values('date') \
    .annotate(dates=Count('date'))
```

Unfortunately that returns `3`, not the expected `2`.

Comment: You could try convert it in to set and get the `len()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the solution was to [aggregate an annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations) and also use the `.distinct()` method to make sure each date is unique.

So final query was:

```py
dates = queryset.annotate(date=TruncDate('created_at')) \
    .values('date') \
    .distinct() \
    .aggregate(dates=Count('date'))
```